# Upload/Display multiple files in localstorage

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make it so you can upload multiple photos to the localstorage with each product having their own upload input. (currently only works for product 1).

I've tried copying the jQuery code and altering the variables but cannot get it to work.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Image: (notice it displays an image on product 1 but not product 2).

[image]

HTML:

```
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Product 1</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="title1" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="text" id="description1" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="file" id="upload1" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField" disabled="disabled" readonly>
        <div class="image1"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Product 2</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="title2" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="text" id="description2" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="file" id="upload2" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField" disabled="disabled" readonly>
        <div class="image2"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Product 3</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="title3" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="text" id="description3" class="form-control editField" readonly>
        <input type="file" id="upload3" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField" disabled="disabled" readonly>
        <div class="image3"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //You might want to do if check to see if localstorage set for theImage here
  var img = new Image();                
  img.src = localStorage.theImage;

  $('.image1').html(img);

  $("body").on("change","#upload1",function(){
      //Equivalent of getElementById
      var fileInput = $(this)[0];//returns a HTML DOM object by putting the [0] since it's really an associative array.
      var file =fileInput.files[0]; //there is only '1' file since they are not multiple type.

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
           // Create a new image.
           var img = new Image();

           img.src = reader.result;
           localStorage.theImage = reader.result; //stores the image to localStorage
           $(".image1").html(img);
       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);//attempts to read the file in question.
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/x1b8nra0/3/. Note that I'd suggest you use `getItem()` and `setItem()` for browser compatibility reasons, but your code will work as-is. If you have issues please check the console for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it works indeed for the first product, however I cannot get it to work with multiple file inputs. Product 2, 3 etc..

Comment: Don't use localStorage to store images or any binary data actually, instead use [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which allows you to store files directly as raw binary data. https://jsfiddle.net/ojrtn0g4/61/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works indeed for the first product, however I cannot get it to work with multiple file inputs

To fix this issue you need to genericise the logic. You can start by using common classes to identify the file inputs and the related div elements that the images should be shown in.

You will then need to store the images in an array. As localStorage only allows string values to be saved you will need to serialise this array. JSON is ideal for this.

Finally you can extract the logic which shows the images from localStorage to a function which can be called on load, and when a new image is set. Try this:

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4f73q1om/) - note this example only works in the fiddle due to SO's restrictions on localStorage access in a snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showImages();

  $("body").on("change", ".file-upload", function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    var file = $input[0].files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
      images[$input.index('.file-upload')] = reader.result;
      localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
      showImages(images);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});

function showImages(content) {
  $('.image').empty();
  var images = content || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
  images.forEach(function(image, i) {
    $('<img />').prop('src', image).appendTo($('.image').eq(i));
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Product 1</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="title1" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="text" id="description1" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="file" id="upload1" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField file-upload" readonly>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <img src="" id="tableBanner" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Product 2</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="title2" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="text" id="description2" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="file" id="upload2" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField file-upload" readonly>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Product 3</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="title3" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="text" id="description3" class="form-control editField" readonly>
    <input type="file" id="upload3" class="btn btn-default btn-file form-control editField file-upload" readonly>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if you do know, but localStorage is not meant to store such data, and such an answer should at least say so, and [redirect to the correct API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) for such tasks.